# Why do I lose stack trace when using async-await in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, stack-trace

When I run the following program

```
async function functionOne() {

  throw new Error('Error here prints the complete stack');

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(); }, 1000);
  });
}

async function functionTwo() {
  await functionOne();
}

async function functionThree() {
  await functionTwo();
}

functionThree()
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I get the following output which prints the stack through the various invoked functions

```
Error: Error here prints the complete stack
    at functionOne (/home/divyanshu/programming/errorHandlingAsyncAwait/index.js:3:9)
    at functionTwo (/home/divyanshu/programming/errorHandlingAsyncAwait/index.js:11:9)
    at functionThree (/home/divyanshu/programming/errorHandlingAsyncAwait/index.js:15:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/divyanshu/programming/errorHandlingAsyncAwait/index.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:653:10)
```

However when the error is thrown after the await call in the following program

```
async function functionOne() {

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(); }, 1000);
  });

  throw new Error('Error here prints incomplete stack');

}

async function functionTwo() {
  await functionOne();
}

async function functionThree() {
  await functionTwo();
}

functionThree()
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

This is the output

```
Error: Error here prints incomplete stack
    at functionOne (/home/divyanshu/programming/errorHandlingAsyncAwait/index.js:7:9)
    at <anonymous>
```

I'd like to understand why the stack trace is lost in the second case but not in the first.

Comment: Hm, async stack traces *should* fix this. What node.js version are you on exactly?

Comment: @Bergi Added the `--async-stack-traces` flag to my answer, but I'm yet to find the exact version where this is supported. I believe it's coming on Node 12

Comment: As per the [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11865) it's scheduled for Node 12. I posted this question more to understand the behavior than any immediate problem

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because in the first code, everything up until the `Error` is on the same tick of the event loop.

Before an asynchronous callback, the one from `setTimeout`, can enter the call stack (The stack trace is built from it), the call stack must be empty.

So since the first code runs everything synchronous until the `Error` call, all those calls are in the call stack. But on the second approach, the `Error` is called after `await`ing a `setTimeout` call. When the `setTimeout` is done. The event loop puts the callback back into the stack, for this, the call stack *must* be empty.

So now, you don't have `functionTwo` & `functionThree` on the call stack, that's why they don't appear.

T**he stack trace is the state of the stack when the error ocurred.**

Here's a rough interpretation of what happens with the stack in both codes:

**First Code**

```
1) functionThree is pushed into the stack
2) functionTwo is pushed into the stack
3) functionOne is pushed into the stack
4) Error is thrown
```

**Second Code**

```
1) functionThree is pushed into the stack
2) functionTwo is pushed into the stack
3) functionOne is pushed into the stack
4) awat ...setTimeout is called
5) All 3 functions return a Promise
6) The stack is empty

... setTimeout ends
Next tick of the event loop

1) setTimeout callback is called
2) Error is thrown
```

I recommend watching this video to understand how all of this works:

[What the heck is the event loop anyway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) by Philip Roberts

---

On Node 14+ you can use `--async-stack-traces` flag to have an improved stack trace when working with asynchronous code. There are some limitations like only working with `async`/`await` and not promises.

You can read a little bit more about this at https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async

Comment: Thanks @marcos. This explains it. The V8 article is a tad complex for me, but I'm really keen to understand the under-the-hood functioning of async-await. Will give it a shot :)