# What happened to --async-stack-traces in node 16+ and is there a new alternative?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stack-trace

Basically, [I have the same question as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162619/why-do-i-lose-stack-trace-when-using-async-await-in-node-js) but for node 16+. The bottom of that answer says:

> On Node 14+ you can use `--async-stack-traces` flag to have an improved stack trace when working with asynchronous code. There are some limitations like only working with `async`/`await` and not promises.
>
> You can read a little bit more about this at https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async

I'm using v16.13.2, and I can't see anything about this flag when I type `node -h | grep async`. Yet, my stack traces are limited to synchronous stacks like the person asking the question. I understand why, but I want to know if there is a way to get better troubleshooting information.

Was the concept of `--async-stack-traces` scrapped? Was it replaced with something else? Is there any way to see asynchronous stack traces in Node 16+? If so, how is it done?

---

**Update:** I found a helpful comment in this [github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30944#issuecomment-593075816): `node --v8-options | grep async` So I guess this flag does exist in 16, but I don't really know how to turn it on, especially when my `package.json` is full of scripts, none of which use `node` directly (Jasmine, Testcafe, Typescript, ts-node).

---

**Update:** I'm even more confused after finding [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35627#issuecomment-707655682).

> This flag is enabled by default in V8. You do not need to pass it.

See here for proof: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5fad0b93667ffc6e4def52996b9529ac99b26319/deps/v8/src/flags/flag-definitions.h#L1730

This doesn't seem like it to me... There must be something specific to the library I'm using.

---

**Update:** Turns out I've been experiencing a [Test Café bug](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6067) this whole time. It had nothing to do with this flag (which is on by default). I suppose this information suffices as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer to this question in my updates above, but to summarize:

1. This flag still exists, but the only way to list it is to run `node --v8-options`
2. This flag is on by default.
3. My symptoms were a [testcafe bug](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6067) that *coincidentally* matched what you would see if async stack traces were off.